# Dataset row number w/ filled rows only

Tags: c#, dataset

If I use `ds.Tables[0].Rows.Count`, I get the row count regardless of if the rows have data in them, I do not want to count the rows that empty, whitespace or null, is there any way to do it actually without reading row by row?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you manage to isolate the rows you want with a filter you can use any of these approaches:

```
DataView myView = new DataVie(ds.Tables[0]);

myView.RowFilter = "NAME IS NOT NULL";

int count = myView.Count;
```

or also with Select...

```
DataRow[] myRows = ds.Tables[0].Select("NAME IS NOT NULL");

int count = myRows.Length;
```

then in the first case you can iterate on the DataView and in the second case you iterate on the DataRow array. For binding to UI Controls DataView is probably better.

Answer (score 0):

yes- `DataTable`  implements the `IEnumerable` interface, which means that you can use LINQ to query it:
`ds.Tables[0].Count(row => !string.IsNullOrEmpty(row["Name"]) /*etc..*/);`
(if you don't already know linq- you should [familiarize yourself](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/bb397933%28v=VS.100%29.aspx). it's great.)